# How to send TLS syslog message via logger command

Tags: syslog, tls

I am working on ubuntu 16.04.

Is there any way to send TLS syslog message by logger command?

Answer (score 5):

## No.

`logger` can only send cleartext data to either a UDP socket, a TCP socket, or a local UNIX Domain Socket (like `/dev/log`, which is the default if `logger` isn't instructed otherwise).

## But.

I assume you have `rsyslog` setup on a remote server (say `syslog-server.mydomain`) to listen on TCP port 6514 because that is the default port when using *Syslog over TLS*. I further assume `rsyslog` on that remote server is configured similar to this:

```
# Certificate configuration for encrypted transmission:
global(
    defaultNetstreamDriver         = "gtls"
    defaultNetstreamDriverCAFile   = "/path/to/root-ca.crt"
    defaultNetstreamDriverCertFile = "/path/to/certificates/server-certificate.crt"
    defaultNetstreamDriverKeyFile  = "/path/to/keys/server-private.key"
)

# Load input module for encrypted TCP to receive messages from the clients:
module(
    load                  = "imtcp" 
    StreamDriver.Name     = "gtls" 
    StreamDriver.Mode     = "1" 
    StreamDriver.AuthMode = "anon"
)

# Ruleset to write externally received messages to a certain file:
ruleset(name="from_remote") {
    action(type="omfile" File="/var/log/messages-from-remote.log")
}

# Bind above ruleset to the TCP listener on port 6514:
input(type="imtcp" port="6514" ruleset="from_remote")
```

Usually (if the remote server wasn't setup to use *Syslog over TLS*) you could issue

```
logger --tcp --server syslog-server.mydomain --port 6514 -p local1.info "Hello World, $RANDOM"
```

but due to `logger`'s inability to handle TLS this does not work. Instead you must prepare a syslog message manually and send it via `gnutls-cli`. Copy the server's CA file to the local machine and then issue:

```
echo "<142>$HOSTNAME Hello World, $RANDOM" | \
    gnutls-cli syslog-server.mydomain --port=6514 --x509cafile=/path/to/root-ca.crt
```

The `<142>` is the encoded value for `local1.info`, `$HOSTNAME` is the source host and the text `Hello World, $RANDOM` is the actual logmessage. `gnutls-cli` reads this string from its *stdin* and sends it to the given server and port using the given CA.

The message should appear on the remote server in the file `/var/log/messages-from-remote.log`.

The tool `gnutls-cli` is part of the package `gnutls-bin` which can be installed via `sudo apt install gnutls-bin`.

---

Of course you can also configure your *local* `rsyslog` to *forward* certain messages via TLS to the remote server and then use `logger` as usual, that is: have `logger` send the messages to the local `rsyslog` daemon (which is the default anyway) and then let your local `rsyslog` forward the encrypted message.

Comment: Of course you can use openssl s_client instead of gnutls-cli. :)

Answer (score 1):

is this still the case? I was able to test Logger for my syslog over TLS just using `logger TEST` The difference is I have a rule set as seen below. This forwards all logs. That being said, it will forward logger Tests via TLS since its rsyslog fwd it not logger.

```
action(type="omfwd"
queue.type="linkedlist"
queue.filename="example_fwd"
target="192.168.0.123"
port="6514"
protocol="tcp"
StreamDriver.Name="gtls"
StreamDriver.Mode= "1"
StreamDriver.AuthMode="x509/name"
StreamDriverPermittedPeers="rsyslog.lab"
```

Comment: Yes, this is still unfortunately the case. What you did is sending the log entry from `logger` to your Rsyslog server via probably unix socket and then `rsyslogd` (and not `logger`) forwarded it via TLS to some other TLS-using syslog server.